# Cannot find typenames ("cannot resolve symbol")

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a site in ASP.NET using Telerik AJAX controls.

Despite the latest binary being added to the website project, my code (eg myRadGrid.Datasource = "";) shows a red line on type names as they cannot be found for some reason.

Can anyone possibly explain why or have experience in this sort of problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did this happen after upgrading to the latest controls, or are these new references?

Comment: Can you try to recompile the application?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assigning an empty string to the radgrid datasource property?  Try setting it to null instead, which is what you do if you want to clear the data source...

Comment: The empty string is just an example. The problem exists even when assigning a datatable or any correct type/variable.